# Slick update optional field

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I am facing a very annoying problem with slick 3.0.x:

Let's consider :

```
case class DbUser(id: Int, username: String, phoneNumber: Option[String], email: Option[String])

val user = DbUser(1, "User", None)
```

if I run :

`users.filter(_.id === user.id).update(user)`

Then, the field phonenumber will be set to null even though the data I send is None, which I can understand, however, how can I not update a field when this one is not defined ? Any ideas >

Comment: In slick, None maps to null

Comment: yes, I understand, but how can I tell slick to distinguish the case phonenumber is None because i want to remove it from the db from the case where phonnumber is None because I dont want to change it

Comment: See my answer below.  I think what you are asking is how to I construct an  update that only updates specific columns

Comment: It's not exactly that. I dont know which field will be in the map as it will depend of the value that is associated to them. I want to be able to edit phoneNumber only if its not None

Comment: You need to select the row, check that the field is a `None` and then modify the object accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To update only select fields, do the following

**Only update username:**

```
users.filter(_.id === user.id)
  .map(_.username)
  .update(user.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on `_.phoneNumber.isDefined`,

```
 import driver.api._

 users.filter(_.phoneNumber.isDefined)
   .map(_.phoneNumber)
   .update(Some("3543453545"))
```